# How to implement error handling in a method with a return type of an interface

Tags: java, methods, try-catch

I have a method that adds to matrices together.  I need to catch an error if the matrices are of different sizes.  When I add the try and catch to my method, I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    This method must return a result of type Matrix

Matrix in an interface, part of the assignment I can not change the return type.  So how do I handle the error and still have the return type be correct?

```
public Matrix plus(Matrix other) throws RuntimeException{
    try {
    int[][] newMatrix = this.cloneMatrix();
    int[][]mMatrix = castFromMatrix(other);

        for (int y = 0; y < mMatrix.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < mMatrix[0].length; x++) {
                newMatrix[y][x] = newMatrix[y][x] + mMatrix[y][x];
            }
        }

        Matrix sumMatrix = new EverhartMatrix(newMatrix);
        return sumMatrix;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Plus method can not be employeed on matrices of different     sizes");}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing its because you are declaring your method to return a `Matrix` object, and in the catch section you are not returning anything, thats why the compiler says This method must return a result of type Matrix, you can just add a `return null;` after your `System.out.println` call and that will fix your problem, keep in mind that returning null is a bad practice so may want to chage the return type to `Optional<Matrix>` and in the case of an exception return an empty Optional.

Comment: What if I have several methods, add, multiply that all need this same try catch?  I know copy paste is not the way to go.  Is there a way to write it once for the whole class?

Comment: You should handle the error in every method or make them throw it up to the caller for it to handle. btw, you should not declare "throws RuntimeException" as it is an unchecked exception and can be thrown from anywhere, you dont need to specify that

Comment: Ok, I was thinking it should have been ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, but the assignment specifies RuntimeException.  Typically you would want to throw the exact exception you are concerned about right?

Comment: yes, but if you are catching the exception in your method, it won't be thrown unless you throw it yourself in code, take a look, at this https://dzone.com/articles/9-best-practices-to-handle-exceptions-in-java it could give you some advice on how to handle exceptions. does this answer your question?

Comment: You can throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because it is a subclass of `RuntimeException`. The easiest way to achieve this is by not catching any exceptions in the first place. If your assignment says the method should declare `throws RuntimeException`, that’s fine. It’s redundant because any code can throw runtime exceptions, even without declaring it, but apparently, someone wanted to be explicit, which is good, as it already tells you that you don’t need to catch these exceptions.